# Is there a way to reduce the vertical white space between input and output in a notebook cell?

Tags: formatting

Is there a way to control the vertical spacing between input and output cells?  If CellMargins is supposed to do it, then what am I doing wrong?
In[8]:= CellMargins -> {{1, 1}, {1, 1}};
a = 7

Out[9]= 7

In[10]:= CellMargins -> {{10, 10}, {100, 100}};
a = 8

Out[11]= 8

In[13]:= CellMargins -> {{5, 5}, {500, 500}};
a = 9

Out[14]= 9

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would control this via a Stylesheet -- and if you search you will find a large number of Q&As about stylesheets on here.

If you really want to do this as input then:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellMargins -> {{5, 5}, {500, 500}}];
a = 8
```

Comment: Thanks, Mike.  That's not working for me.  There must be something elementary I'm missing.  Where is EvaluationCell in the Options Inspector?  I'm new at this.  What does changing the option affect?  Only new cells?  New notebooks?  Existing notebook?  Old notebooks when reopened?  I think all these questions apply to style sheets too.  If I change a stylesheet and apply it to a notebook, should the changes occur immediately?  Will changing a style sheet reformat old notebooks?  Documentation I've found so far assumes readers already know all this.